# Should i check for filepath exist before streaming text into file

Tags: vb.net, file-io

I have following code:

```
Dim fs As FileStream
fs = New FileStream(path, FileMode.Create)

Dim sw As StreamWriter
sw = New StreamWriter(os)
sw.Write(something)
sw.Flush()
```

Is this a correct way to do this? Do i need to put in some checks to see if file exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do i need to put in some checks to see if file exists?

It depends on what you are trying to do. If you want to overwrite the file, then no. `FileMode.Create` will always overwrite an existing file, or if it doesn't exist, create it:

> [**Create**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filemode.aspx)
>
> Specifies that the operating system should create a new file. If the file already exists, it will be overwritten. This operation requires FileIOPermissionAccess.Write permission. System.IO.FileMode.Create is equivalent to requesting that if the file does not exist, use CreateNew; otherwise, use Truncate. If the file already exists but is a hidden file, an UnauthorizedAccessException exception is thrown.

If you don't want to overwrite an existing file, then yes you should check it. Something like this:

```
If Not File.Exists(path) Then
    Using fs As New FileStream(path, FileMode.CreateNew), sw As New StreamWriter(fs)
        sw.Write("Something")
    End Using
End If
```

You'll also notice that I used `CreateNew` instead of `Create`. This is an additional safety check to ensure that an existing file is never overwritten. With `CreateNew`, an exception is raised if the file already exists. You should still check if it exists however, since we don't want the exception to happen in the first place.